# how do I import compass css3 module into a Foundation 5 project

Tags: zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm creating Foundation 5 project using bower with:

foundation new PROJECT_NAME

I wanted to use the compass css3 mixin but I cannot understand how to import it or even if it is present in the project.

thankyou
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the perfect answer from ZURB

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/513-adding-compass-to-new-project

> There has been an updated install guide on the Docs page:
>
> http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html
>
> In the command line, run 'foundation new MY_PROJECT' by replacing MY_PROJECT with the folder you want to install the project on. After that, confirm that these folders exist on the directory you specified.
>
> When starting a project run compass init and then compass watch (in Terminal) to watch for changes on the .sass files.
>
> Then change the import of settings in app.scss from:
>
> @import "settings";
>
> To:
>
> @import "foundation/_settings";
>
> Once you've done that, run compass watch again.

Answer (score 3):

I've started a project with Zurb Foundation 5 with Bower + Grunt + Libsass (as they recommend). I wanted to use, as Francesco Pensabene, a compass mixin (the sticky footer). I followed the instructions Using [Foundation With Grunt + Libsass](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html). The project is created successfully, but the **Compass** thing didn't work. I want to add in my **app.scss**:

```
@import
    "settings",
    "foundation/components/top-bar",
    "foundation/components/offcanvas",
    "compass/layout/sticky-footer";  //THE COMPASS MIXIN
```

Running **foundation update** doesn't add the compass mixins. To achieve it, I've gone through the following steps:

**1.** Foundation uses **Bower** (package manager). Install it with:

```
[sudo] npm install -g bower grunt-cli
```

**2.** Create the project as the documentation says:

```
foundation new project_name --libsass
```

**3.** Edit the **project_name/bower.json** file and add a dependency:

```
{
    "name": "foundation-libsass-template",
    "dependencies": {
        "foundation": "zurb/bower-foundation",
        "compass-mixins": "Igosuki/compass-mixins"
    }
}
```

Add the **`"compass-mixins": "Igosuki/compass-mixins"`**. It's a repository with all the compass mixins ready to use with **libsass**.

**4.** Update the project (it'll download all the **compass mixins** and place them in the **brower_components**'s folder)

```
foundation update
```

**5.** Edit Grunt.js and add the path where the new donloaded mixins are located.

```
(...)
options: {
    includePaths: [
        'bower_components/foundation/scss',
        'bower_components/compass-mixins/lib'
    ]
},
(...)
```

That's all. Now in your **app.scss** file you can import whatever compass mixin you like. Compile with `grunt build`, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

use this on your scss file where you import your other components (eg. foundation.scss) :

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Comment: do you have compass installed?

Answer (score 0):

be sure to install compass and create a compass project in your foundation project

```
gem install compass
cd <myproject>
compass create
```

then

```
@import "compass";
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default CLI method provided by Zurb uses compass, compass will need to be installed already. This can be accomplished by

**Bash**

```
[sudo] npm install -g bower grunt-cli

[sudo] gem install compass

[sudo] gem install foundation
```

Default foundation install method uses compass

```
foundation new MY_PROJECT
```

Now be sure to run an update (not needed but good idea anyway)

```
cd MY_PROJECT

foundation update
```

At this point you can edit you scss/app.scss file to resemble what I have below to make sure compass is playing ball.

**scss/app.scss**

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";

$default-text-shadow-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1.0);
$default-text-shadow-blur: 5px;
$default-text-shadow-v-offset: 2px;

@import "compass/css3";

// Uses defaults set before the import above
.has-single-shadow {
  @include single-text-shadow;
}

// Can output up to ten text shadows
.has-custom-shadow {
  @include text-shadow(rgba(blue, 0.2) 1px 1px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 2px 2px 0, rgba(blue, 0.2) 3px 3px 0);
}
```